# Maxlength check using JQuery For multiline text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPurpose" CssClass="dd" runat="server" MaxLength="500" OnKeyUp="return maxlength();" OnPaste="return maxlength();" TextMode="MultiLine"
                                Width="70%" Rows="4" ValidationGroup="tool"></asp:TextBox>
```

in javascript

```
function maxlength()
        {

            var max = 500;
            if ($('.dd').focus().val().length > max)
            {
                $('.dd').val($('.dd').val().substr(0, max));
            }
            $('.charsRemaining').html('You have ' + (max - $('.dd').val().length) + ' characters remaining');
        }
```

it is working fine but when copying something and pasting it in textarea using mouse right click $('.dd').focus().val() is coming as empty string. what to do

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is that the contents of the clipboard have not been transferred to the textbox at the point you capture the event.

The following should help:

```
    event.returnValue = false;
    var clipString = window.clipboardData.getData("Text", sNewString);
```

See [Microsoft OnPaste event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info.

However, beware of the onpaste event.

From http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/extended-event-attributes/onpaste:

> Its a non-standard event defined by
>   Microsoft for use in Internet
>   Explorer. It may work in some other
>   browsers but cannot be reliably used.
>   Compatibility for this non-standard
>   attribute not tested.

Comment: are there any cross browser fix for this issue the above one is working in IE only as you have mentioned